# Jquery last selector solution

Tags: jquery

I have created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dF22/) with this code:

This is my problem I want to make same behavior by selecting **last** li (fifth) tag  but **not** the **fourth** like in this example ,but I don't know how to accomplish that:(

I hope that someone can help me with this...THX!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("button").click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active')
      if ($('ul li:last').hasClass('active')) {
          $('ul li:last').removeClass('active')
          $('ul li:first').addClass('active')
      }

  });


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put part in an `else` block. Otherwise, both methods will run twice for the last list item, causing the last element to be "skipped".

A better solution (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9dF22/5/ ):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var $li = $('ul li'),
            $active = $li.filter('.active:first'),
            $next = $active.next();
        $active.removeClass('active');
        if ($next.length) {               // length === 0 if there is no next one
            $next.addClass('active');
        } else {
            $li.first().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9dF22/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        if ($('ul li:last').hasClass('active')) {
            $('ul li:last').removeClass('active')
            $('ul li:first').addClass('active')
        } else {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just another way to accopmplish the same. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9dF22/4/). In this case you just check weather there is a subsequenc `li` and swap to first if there isn't.

Comment: +1. The same answer as me, except posted first (though it looks like I updated the fiddle first).

Answer (score 1):

I got much better way to do this

```
$("button").click(function() {
    if($('.active').next('li').length != 0) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active')
    } else {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');   
        $("ul li").first().addClass('active');
    }      
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/9dF22/7/)